# Delete multiple rows using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

When deleting data related to an object in an HttpDelete call using Entity Framework Core, I can do this:

```
var video = _context.VideoList.Where(x => x.VideoId == nodeList.VideoId).FirstOrDefault();
```

But what if I have multiple rows that needed deleted using the same VideoId? Also the two entities are not related in the database(no foreign keys).

I've found answers that use a List then use RemoveRange, but I just need to delete potentially multiple records using the same ID...I know in SQL it would look like this:

```
DELETE FROM VideoList WHERE VideoId = '111xxx333aaa'
```

Is there a way to do this in EF core?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in 2 steps :

- Even if your entities are not related get them in an IEnumerable like a List

`var videos = _context.VideoList.Where(x => x.VideoId == nodeList.VideoId).ToList();`

- And then remove them with a RemoveRange

`_context.VideoList.RemoveRange(videos);`